# Consecutive character matching and extraction with position

Tags: r, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds, grepl

I'm trying to write a generic code in R where I look for 2 (or more in the future) explicit characters in a specific order located consecutively in the vector. Every command I am trying will only return a match for the first character.

I have a character string that looks similar to data and I want to extract the positions that have "L" and "V" next to each other only and in that order. So the only matches I have should be positions 3 & 4 and 7 & 8; However, I will get back positions 1, 3, and 7 as a match for L. Is it possible to only return "LV" matches?

Reproducible data to work with:

```
data <- c("L", "D", "L", "V", "A", "V", "L", "V")
```

Answer (score 0):

The vector `data` could first be collapsed into one string with `paste`. Then we can find the starting positions via `gregexpr`.  After that, we can form a list of the start and finish points by concatenating the result from `gregexpr` with the adjusted match length attribute.

```
x <- gregexpr("LV", paste(data, collapse = ""))[[1]]
Map(c, x, x + attr(x, "match.length") - 1)
# [[1]]
# [1] 3 4
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 7 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possibilities:

```
which(ts(data) == "L" & stats::lag(ts(data)) == "V")
## [1] 3 7

which(head(data, -1) == "L" & tail(data, -1) == "V")
## [1] 3 7

which(apply(t(embed(data, 2)) == c("V", "L"), 2, all))
## [1] 3 7

which(data == "L" & dplyr::lead(data) == "V")
## [1] 3 7
```